# Show that $x=2\ln(3x-2)$ can be written as $x=\frac{1}{3}(e^{x/2}+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

> Show that $x=2\ln(3x-2)$ can be written as $x=\dfrac{1}{3}(e^{x/2}+2)$.

Is there a rule for this?

Comment: What do you mean "x equals something that depends on x"...?

Comment: I suppose it means that x is a solution for the first equation iff it's a solution of the second one.

Comment: Hollie Mollie! As time passes by I find it harder and harder to understand some students...Thanks, @mm-aops

Comment: @DonAntonio Exam boards* haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve for the "other" $x$. Notice that:
$$ \begin{align*}
x &= 2\ln(3x-2) \\
\dfrac{x}{2} &= \ln(3x-2) \\
e^{x/2} &= 3x-2 \\
e^{x/2}+2 &= 3x \\
\dfrac{1}{3}(e^{x/2}+2) &= x \\
\end {align*} $$
as desired.

Comment: Actually I think the question would have been better phrased as showing that $x = 2\ln(3y - 2)$ is equivalent to $y = \frac13(e^{x/2} + 2)$ and then pointing out the special $x = y$ case of it. :)

Answer (score 2):

It’s just the relationship between logs and exponents. Starting with $x=2\ln(3x-2)$, divide both sides by $2$ to get

$$\frac{x}2=\ln(3x-2)\;.$$

Now exponentiate on both sides:

$$e^{\frac{x}2}=e^{\ln(3x-2)}=3x-2\;,$$

because by definition $e^{\ln u}=u$ for all $u>0$. Finally, add $2$ to both sides to get

$$e^{\frac{x}2}+2=3x\;,$$

and multiply both sides by $\frac13$, and you’re done.

Answer (score -1):

exponential function is injective, so $x = y$ iff $e^x = e^y$. use this fact and then some elementary symbol manipulations should give you the desired result (if it's true of course)

Comment: If you can't be bothered to work it out for yourself, it is better to refrain from answering. Possibly, this could have been suitable as a comment.

Comment: @Lord_Farin - I disagree. This answer provides a useful hint that could allow the asker of the question to work the problem out for him/herself and so learn some maths in the process.

Comment: @user12477 It is not so much the content of the answer that I have an issue with, but rather how it is phrased.